# Insert BLOB data into SQLite database field using Matlab and SQL query. Any idea?

Tags: sql, matlab, sqlite, blob

I need to store binary data in single database field (DB is SQLite, it's important!). Binary data is a some one-dimensional array.One of the best way to do that is BLOB data insertion. As far as I know Matlab doesn't consist methods for BLOB data processing. How can I do that using Matlab environment? Maybe using raw SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a raw SQLite query, a blob can be written as a `x`-prefixed string, with each byte representeded by a two-digit hexadecimal number:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable(BlobColumn) VALUES(x'0123AB');
```

To return a blob as text from a query, you can use the [quote() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#quote), which uses the same format:

```sql
SELECT quote(BlobColumn) FROM MyTable;  --> returns the string "x'0123AB'"
```

It might be a better idea to use some other SQLite3 driver for Matlab, e.g., https://github.com/kyamagu/matlab-sqlite3-driver, http://jaewon.mine.nu/jaewon/2015/06/17/another-sqlite-interface-for-matlab/.